# How Execute Stored Procedure using JPA annotation @NamedStoredProcedureQuery

Tags: java, sql, jpa, stored-procedures

How convert this procedure execution using @NamedStoredProcedureQuery?

I have this SQL, It's OK!

**SQL  (it's Works OK):**

```
USE [INTEGRADOR]
GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SP_VW_PEDIDOSDECOMPRA_SGM]
        @CODIGO = 71648

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value 

GO
```

---

In Java i Try this, but not working. idUsuarioAutenticado is @CODIGO = 71648

---

**JAVA  (Error when compile) :**

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
            name = "listarComprasMicrosigaProc", 
            procedureName = "INTEGRADOR.DBO.SP_VW_PEDIDOSDECOMPRA_SGM", 
            resultClasses = AcompanhamentoCompraPortalEntity.class, 
            parameters = {
                @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.IN, type = Long.class)
            }
        )
    public List<AcompanhamentoCompraPortalEntity> listarComprasMicrosigaProc(@Param("idUsuarioAutenticado") Long idUsuarioAutenticado);
```

Not compile.

I received this errors:

> The annotation @NamedStoredProcedureQuery is disallowed for this location

**My imports (Java) :**

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaSpecificationExecutor;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of at *field*/attribute level, you have to add the `@NamedStoredProcedureQuery` annotation and its details at *class* level:

```
@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
// further specifications ...
)
public class MyEntity {
      // fields, getter/setter methods, etc.
}
```

With that corrected, the error (message)

> The annotation @NamedStoredProcedureQuery is disallowed for this location

should disappear.

Hope it helps.